# Recalculated totals not saved after removing order items in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

I'm using Wordpress 4.9.6 and WooCommerce 3.4.2 on a Woocommerce site and where I have a custom feature that creates invoices for event registrations.

Right now I'm working on a script that will just remove one item from an existing order.  The items remove fine, but the total doesn't recalculate.  I can view the order in wp-admin and recalculate the totals from there fine, but I need it to happen in this script.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's keeping this from working...

My actual code:

```
$order = wc_get_order($event_registration['OrderID']);

if ( count($order->get_items()) > 1 ) {
  if ( !wc_delete_order_item($event_registration['OrderItemID']) ) {
    return array('error' => 'Problem removing order item');
  }

  $updated_order = wc_get_order($event_registration['OrderID']);

  if ( count($updated_order->get_items()) > 0) {
    $updated_order->calculate_totals();
    PluginWoo::update_invoice($updated_order->get_id());

    return true;
  } else {
    if ( !wp_delete_post( $event_registration['OrderID'], true ) ) {
      return array('error' => 'Problem deleting order after deleting items');
    }
    return true;
  }
} else {
  if ( !wp_delete_post( $event_registration['OrderID'], true ) ) {
    return array('error' => 'Problem deleting order');
  }
  return true;
}
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Yes you are right, calculated_totals include save… So tell me please, if you find out the way, as your code is not testable…

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if there is a WooCommerce bug at work here.  calculate_totals is returning a total if I echo it, but it's the total prior to the item being removed by wc_delete_order_item.  I wrote another short script to just run calculate_totals separately on an order and if I run that after this script separately the order ends up with the proper total. It's like wc_delete_order_item is running asynchronously and not completing before calculate_totals but I didn't think that was possible in PHP.  Thoughts?

Comment: Based on your comment, I have an updated my answer below, that could work, using the CRUD `WC_Data` `delete()` method instead of old habitual `wc_delete_order_item()` function. Now as I can not test anything, this is just an imaginative way…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's like `wc_delete_order_item()` function is running asynchronously and not completing before `calculate_totals()` method, you could try to use [`WC_Data` `delete()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_delete) instead.

As your code is not really testable, I am just wondering. So you could try something like:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $event_registration['OrderID'] );
$items = $order->get_items();
if ( count($items) > 1 ) {
    if( isset( $items[$event_registration['OrderItemID']] ) )
        $items[$event_registration['OrderItemID']]->delete(); // Deleting
    else
        return array('error' => 'Problem removing order item'); // Returning error
}

$updated_order = wc_get_order( $event_registration['OrderID'] );
$items = $updated_order->get_items();
if ( count($items) > 0 ) {
    $updated_order->calculate_totals();

    PluginWoo::update_invoice($updated_order->get_id());
    return true;
} else {
    if( isset( $items[$event_registration['OrderItemID']] ) )
        $items[$event_registration['OrderItemID']]->delete(); // Deleting
    else
        return array('error' => 'Problem deleting order after deleting items');

    return true;
}
```

It could works…

Comment: WC_Data delete method did the trick.  Now I'm going to go through all my code and use this anywhere that wc_delete_order_item was being used before.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of WooCommerce, if you want to delete the items from the order you can use remove_item() method from Order class. for an example:

```
$order = wc_get_order( 1111 );
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $items ) {
 $order->remove_item( $item_id );
}
$order->calculate_totals();
```

Thanks